# Unable to add web part to catalog pipeline azure - access denied

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-devops, spfx

I have created a pipeline to bundle and add a webpart to the app catalog. I am getting this access error below. Any ideas?

```
2019-10-17T16:28:44.6630984Z ##[section]Starting: add package to catalog
2019-10-17T16:28:44.6740356Z ==============================================================================
2019-10-17T16:28:44.6740433Z Task         : Command line
2019-10-17T16:28:44.6740486Z Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
2019-10-17T16:28:44.6740546Z Version      : 2.151.2
2019-10-17T16:28:44.6740587Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-10-17T16:28:44.6740630Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
2019-10-17T16:28:44.6740689Z ==============================================================================
2019-10-17T16:28:45.4965469Z Generating script.
2019-10-17T16:28:45.5061921Z Script contents:
2019-10-17T16:28:45.5070670Z o365 spo app add -p d:\a\r1\a/_ABFI-CI/drop/sharepoint/solution/json-feed.sppkg --overwrite
2019-10-17T16:28:45.5392405Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2019-10-17T16:28:45.5641516Z ##[command]"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "d:\a\_temp\6ca1b36f-40ef-444b-ae13-9e5ba3ba5d98.cmd""
2019-10-17T16:28:49.1097084Z Error: Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access t**strong text**his resource.
2019-10-17T16:28:49.2305193Z ##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
2019-10-17T16:28:49.2676400Z ##[section]Finishing: add package to catalog
```

Comment: Where are you defining the credentials to use?

Comment: Did you specify the user account? Did the user account have the permission about adding package?

Comment: I just needed to be added as an admin to the site

Comment: If you execute this command locally instead of the azure pipeline, will you get the same error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to be added as an admin to the site!